# Use Etherescan api with ERC1155?

Tags: etherscan

I can see that etherscan has a tab for ERC1155 transactions for a specific address, but I dont see in their api how to get data for this type of ERC. Is there a endpoint that gives this type of data?

I do see on this page there is an options for ERC721 which seems to work just fine https://etherscan.io/apidocs#accounts, but is there a way to get the same data they display on the ERC1155 tab?

Comment: I reached out to Etherscan today specifically about this. They confirmed it is a works in progress at the moment. They will update docs and announce it on twitter when deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan now have api for getting ERC-1155 transaction here:

https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-erc1155-token-transfer-events-by-address

Use it the same way with normal transactions.